# Using janusgraph's withRemote traversal(gremlin language) seems having trouble with Index

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I'm using Elastic Search as index server. And I have an index with property "poiId", but when I added a new vertex with that property and then search for it using the same remote traversal, it found nothing. So it continues adding new vertexes. What's wrong with code?

```
public class Loader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Graph graph = EmptyGraph.instance();
    List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(args[0])), "UTF-8");
    for (String line : lines) {
        GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal().withRemote("remote-graph.properties");
        String[] cols = StringUtils.split(line, ",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(cols));
        GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> t1 = g.V().has("poiId", cols[0]);
        GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> t2 = g.V().has("poiId", cols[1]);
        Object v1Id = null;
        if (!t1.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("cols1 ADDED: %s", cols[0]));
            v1Id = g.addV().property("poiId", cols[0]).next().id();
        } else {
            v1Id = t1.next().id();
        }

        Object v2Id = null;
        if (!t2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("cols2 ADDED: %s", cols[1]));
            v2Id = g.addV().property("poiId", cols[1]).next().id();
        } else {
            v2Id = t2.next().id();
        }
        g.V(v1Id).as("a").V(v2Id).as("b").addE("relation").property("step", Integer.parseInt(cols[2])).from("a")
                .to("b").next();

        g.close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How did you define the index? What does the `remote-graph.properties` look like?

Comment: @JasonPlurad I think the index is not working, the janus graph 's ES client is outdated...

Comment: Are you using an ES version that is compatible with the JanusGraph [supported version](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/version-compat.html)? For exact match lookups, you don't need ES anyway. [Composite index](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html#graph-indexes) would be fine. My questions from before still stand.